# Drupal 7 - Content type inside a content type - Like field collection

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-content-types, drupal-field-collection

I´d like to create a content type called "contact" that will be share in other content types, like "client" and "prospect". When I create a new client, I´d like to be able to create, in the same form, new contacts for this client, like a field collection. For example:

ADD NEW CLIENT

Name:

Firm:

Email:

Contacts (multiple value)

---

Name:

Email:

---

Add new contact

But, in the "Contact" content type I have a lot more fields that I can fill up later:

Name:
Email:
Phone:
Address:
City:
State....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to setup a rule that whenever a new 'Client' entity is created  a new 'Contact' entity is created based on the values in the client contacts fields (name and email).

However I am unsure as to how you could implement an 'add another item' for field groups in a form (which is what I assume is the desired functionality of your 'Add new contact').

You may also want to make sure to include an [entity reference field](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) on your contact entity type, so that it can reference the client entity to which it is related. That would give you the option in the future to display a view of contacts related to a client.